# MySQL update field with WHERE from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE table1 
SET description = 'New description' 
WHERE language_code = 'en' AND table2 default_category_id = '11'
```

How to use this correctly with table1 and table2. I can only work it out when using table1.

Comment: Can you share the tables' structures and some sample data to make this question easier to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a relationship between the tables.

```
update table1
set description = 'New desc'
where language_code = 'en'
and some_column in (select related_column 
                    from table2 
                     where default_category_id = '11')
```

Comment: Is some_column and related_column the same column? Not getting this. I get this error instead #1054 - Unknown column 'default_category_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: some_column is a column in table 1 that has a corresponding value in table 2 (related_column), PK/FK, join column, fundamental concept of *relational* databases...

Comment: @medgalys without your db structure any answer is possible here, but to be more specific you will need to provide your db structure. What JohnHC gave you is an idea of how to do it, you will need to replace fields accordingly

Comment: Thanks @JohnHC! Solved it.

Answer (score 0):

try using join between 2 tables

```
update table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
set t1.desired_column = "value"
where t2.desired_column = "value"
```